# Select a row in a DataGridView, from the index of the DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I populate from a view in PostgreSQL:

```
dataSource = new BindingSource();
dgData.DataSource = dataSource;
dataSource.DataSource = Program.DB.GetView(dbView, filter);
```

(`Program.DB.GetView` returns a `DataTable`)

when I have a row selected and I sort the `DataGridView`, my selection is stuck at the same index. I want the selection to stay at the selected record.

I have tried to get the first column (which is the database's primary key) and use that to refer a row in the view, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```
if (dgData.SelectedRows.Count == 1) {
     rowIdx = (int)dgData.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
     colName = dgData.Columns[0].Name;
}
```

Now, how to use the `rowIdx` to set a row's `Selected` property in the `DataGridView` to `true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest LinQ to get your row, then set the selected property :

```
DataGridViewRow searchedRow = (from row in dgData.rows
                               where row.Cells[0].value == rowIdx
                               select row).FirstOrDefault();
if(searchedRow != null)
    searchedRow.Selected = true;
```

Another solution to retrieve the row (with Lambda):

```
searchedRow = dgData.rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells[0].value == rowIdx);
```

Or if you don't have to do anything else with the `Row`, you can go with :

```
dgData.rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
           .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells[0].value == rowIdx)
           .Selected = true
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't seem to work. `dgData.Rows` has no `FirstOrDefault` member.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Does the `Cast` call help ? (Is first solution solving your issue ?)

Comment: Just tested the second and third solution with a fresh c# express, and it is ok. I think third is best for your needs.